# Value resetting when a method is called within the onload

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax

```
window.onload = init;

function init(){
   initializeEventHandlers();
   getData(formatDate(new Date));
   gotoDate('today');
}

//scripts that manage the UI for tracker.aspx
var dCurrentDate, sCurrentDate, sCurrentDayData, stepsVal, chipsVal, dayValue, dateValue, caloriesVal;
var fCurrentValue = 0;
var bAnimating, bSliding = false;

   //scripts that manage the UI for tracker.aspx
    var dCurrentDate, sCurrentDate, sCurrentDayData, stepsVal, chipsVal, dayValue, dateValue, caloriesVal;
    var fCurrentValue = 0;
    var bAnimating, bSliding = false;

getData(d)
{
  steps = 5;
  calories = 10;
  chipsAmount = 3;
}


//I expect this to be 5+1, but it actually through an exception. I am wondering if its cause steps is not yet loaded. What can I do to make this actually 5 + 1.
steps + 1;
```

I load data from an XML which the sets some values. The probem I am facing is that when i set the values in the GetData method. The vars declared lose there value after the onload. What am i doing wrong and how can i make the values retain

Comment: Are you loading the data asynchronously? If so, the values might not exist at the time you're trying to set them, so you should load it synchronously with your script. Otherwise I'm not really sure I understand your question completely.

Comment: Yeah i am loading synchronously

Comment: the problem mainly is that i need to set the variables at onload so that other functions can use them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the variables you're loading the data into defined in the global scope? From your getData() function, if you're setting the data to the steps, calories, and chipsAmount variables, they won't be accessible outside that function. You'll have to define those three variables outside the function so that they're in the global scope.

Comment: variables used inside a function not declared using var are owned by the global object (ie, window) and are indeed accessible elsewhere irrespective of whether they've been declared globally